# Calculate IN/OUT by employee on time clock over SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

My problem is simple.

I have this table that saves one row every time an employee use his time card on the clock:

```
EmployeeID      DateTime
----------      --------------------
1               2016-02-16 07:00 am
1               2016-02-16 06:30 pm
1               2016-02-17 07:15 am
2               2016-02-17 09:00 am
1               2016-02-17 11:30 am
1               2016-02-17 01:45 pm
1               2016-02-17 06:45 pm
2               2016-02-17 06:45 pm
```

What I need is to calculate a column that determine if the employee in IN or OUT the office. To do so i estimate that the first record of each day for each employee is IN, the next OUT, the next IN and so on.

So the result for the given example should be:

```
EmployeeID      DateTime                INOUT
----------      --------------------    -----
1               2016-02-16 07:00 am     IN
1               2016-02-16 06:30 pm     OUT
1               2016-02-17 07:15 am     IN
2               2016-02-17 09:00 am     IN
1               2016-02-17 11:30 am     OUT
1               2016-02-17 01:45 pm     IN
1               2016-02-17 06:45 pm     OUT
2               2016-02-17 06:45 pm     OUT
```

I guess i need to join each record with the previous, and then calculate but don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`, no need to join the table with itself:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY [DateTime])
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  *,
        CASE WHEN RN % 2 = 1 THEN 'IN' ELSE 'OUT' END INOUT
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Not that it matters much but the cte shouldn't be needed as you can wrap the window function in the case expression directly. It's nice for readability though.

Comment: @jpw yes, I'm aware of that, but I prefer the `CTE` for readability, as you said

Comment: Excelent! Works perfect. Thank you

Comment: Well, after some test i found something missing. In your query partition is made by emploeeID. The problem is that the row number must restart for each employee and each day, so I add date part as a second condition for the partition.

Comment: @ericpap Can you show what you did to add a second condition for the partition?